# Wait for specific time after function call in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, timer, thread-sleep

I have a function call and I need to wait for 5 seconds after I call it. I do not wait to use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5]` or a simple `sleep(5)` since this is running on the main thread and I will end up blocking my entire application.

functionality desired:

1. function call
2. sleep for 5 secs
3. continue processing other functions

How can I do this on Objective-C?

Comment: If the *function call* is something asynchronous don't wait, proceed in the completion handler.

Comment: yes the function call is a set property and it is asynchronous. But there is no completion handler or call back I can wait for. So the wait for 5 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about dispatch_after?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452876-dispatch_after

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // throw your call to other functions in here
});
```